# Show that order of $ \{ a: x^{2} \equiv a ( \mathrm{mod} p), p \ \mathrm{prime}, \ x \not = 0 \} $ is $ \dfrac{p-1}{2} $

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

As above. I can show that this forms a group (under multiplication mod p) so clearly $ \dfrac{p-1}{2} $ is a possibility. But I must be missing something obvious as I don't see how to prove it.

Any help/ a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Many ways to proceed. Possibly the one putting least demands on your background is to first show that $x^2\equiv y^2$ if and only if $x\equiv-y$. If you can pull that off, then it follows that $x\mapsto x^2$ is a 2-1 mapping, and hence the image has half the size.

Comment: But, have you searched the site? It is quite llikely that very closely related questions have already been handled. Alas, the search engine sucks with formulas.

Comment: Have a look at the very pedagogical presentation of (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue). See on this site (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/151530)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You mean $x\equiv \pm y$.

Comment: $x^2\equiv y^2\pmod{p}$ if and only if $p\mid x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$. By [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) this is equivalent to either $p\mid x+y$ or $p\mid x-y$, i.e. $x\equiv \pm y\pmod{p}$. From this the fact that there are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ non-zero quadratic residues mod an odd prime $p$ follows.

Comment: If you know about primitive roots, this is fairly straightforward, because squares are precisely even powers of your primitive root.