# Determinant of Bilinear space

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

This is [Definition 1.3.16, Definition 1.3.17](https://books.google.com/books?id=c27pCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA11)  from Scharlau's book *Quadratic and Hermitian Forms*

[image]

My question is what is well defined upto squares mean in definition 3.17
Also in second line of 3.17 det(V,b) is element of $K^.$/$K^.2$ what is meaning of that? Say we have real number field with exclusion of 0 as $K^.$ for the bilinear form b then; what it means is if it is nonsingular then det(V,b) is all elements excluding squares. Is it right or wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $K^\cdot/(K^\cdot)^2$ simply means quotient group of $K^\cdot$ by the subgroup $(K^\cdot)^2$ consisting of all squares.
In other words, these are the equivalence classes of $K^\cdot$ if you take equivalence relation
$$k\sim k' \Leftrightarrow k'k^{-1}\in(K^\cdot)^2.$$

You can find more information in the Wikipedia article [Square class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_class). Some examples are listed on [GroupProps](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_a_field_modulo_squares).

In the fields you encounter most frequently this is quite simple. Every complex number has a square root, so if $K=\mathbb C$ you only have one class. If $K=\mathbb R$ you get two classes, positive and negative numbers (squares and non-squares). Similarly in finite fields you have at most two classes, see here: [The number of elements which are squares in a finite field.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/151530)

---

The phrase "well defined up to square" means exactly what is written in the following sentence: "$\det B$ and $\det B'$ differ only by element of $(K^\cdot)^2$". The other way to put is is that you can assign in this way to $(V,b)$ the equivalence class od $\det B$ w.r.t. to the equivalence relation described above.